# construct mongoDB query dynamically in Pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb

I have SCIM search request body like this,

```
{
     "schemas": ["urn:ietf:params:scim:api:messages:2.0:SearchRequest"],
     "attributes": ["displayName", "userName"],
     "excludedAttributes": ["emails"],
     "filter":"displayName sw \"smith\"",
     "startIndex": 1,
     "count": 10,
     "sortBy": "userName",
     "sortOrder": "ascending"
   }
```

all the above attributes are optional, except for "schemas" attribute.

because, all the attributes are optional i have construct query accordingly.

below is the code for this handling, as you can see there are conditions which make code look untidy.

```
data = request.get_json()
a = {}
attributes = data.get('attributes',[])
sortby = data.get('sortBy',None)
sortorder = data.get('sortOrder',None)
if not attributes:
    pass
else:
    for i in attributes:
        if i not in a:
            a[i]=1
excludedAttributes = data.get('excludedAttributes',[])
if not excludedAttributes:
    pass
else:
    for i in excludedAttributes:
        if i not in a:
            a[i]=0
if not a and not sortby:
    result = mongo.db.test.find({}, )
if a and not sortby:
    result = mongo.db.test.find({}, a)
if not a and sortby and not sortorder:
    result = mongo.db.test.find({}, ).sort([(sortby,flask_pymongo.ASCENDING)])
if a and sortby and not sortorder:
    result = mongo.db.test.find({}, a).sort([(sortby, flask_pymongo.ASCENDING)])
if not a and sortby and sortorder=='ascending':
    result = mongo.db.test.find({}, ).sort([(sortby, flask_pymongo.ASCENDING)])
if a and sortby and not sortorder=='ascending':
    result = mongo.db.test.find({}, a).sort([(sortby, flask_pymongo.ASCENDING)])
if not a and sortby and sortorder=='descending':
    result = mongo.db.test.find({}, ).sort([(sortby, flask_pymongo.DESCENDING)])
if a and sortby and not sortorder=='descending':
    result = mongo.db.test.find({}, a).sort([(sortby, flask_pymongo.DESCENDING)])
for i in result:
    full_data.append(i)
resp = jsonify(json.loads(dumps(full_data)))
return resp
```

if i include even pagination, there will be even more conditions piling up.
How do i construct these queries effectively.

Comment: This is a question for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 0):

```
data = request.get_json()
a = {}
attributes = data.get('attributes',[])
sortby = data.get('sortBy',None)
sortorder = data.get('sortOrder',None)
if not attributes:
    pass
else:
    for i in attributes:
        if i not in a:
            a[i]=1
excludedAttributes = data.get('excludedAttributes',[])
if not excludedAttributes:
    pass
else:
    for i in excludedAttributes:
        if i not in a:
            a[i]=0

result = mongo.db.test.find({}, )
if a:
    result = mongo.db.test.find({}, a)
if sortby:
    if sortorder == "descending":
        sortorder = flask_pymongo.DESCENDING
    else:
        sortorder = flask_pymongo.ASCENDING
    result = result.sort([(sortby, sortorder)])
for i in result:
    full_data.append(i)
resp = jsonify(json.loads(dumps(full_data)))
return resp
```